# How to pass object in views in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm having a set of html codes which are being called in a `foreach statement` in `views`, I'm trying to push `array of object` to get the views through `controller`.

Following is my **controller** code:

```
public function get_template($id)
{
    $template = Template::findOrFail($id);
    $getplugin = json_decode($template->templatedata);
    $plugins = Plugin::all();
    $userid = $template->user->id;
    return view('nitseditor.test', ['plugins' => $plugins, 'template'=> $template, 'getplugin' => $getplugin, 'userid' => $userid]);
}
```

In my **views** I'm calling like this:

```
@foreach($getplugin as $renderer)

   @include('themes.' . $template->theme->name . '.Plugins.' . $plugins->find($renderer)->type . '.' . $plugins->find($renderer)->id, ['content' => $plugins->find($renderer)->userplugins()->whereUserId($userid)->first()->pivot->contents])

@endforeach
```

**Views** or **HTML code** which are being **generated**:

```
<div id="slideshow">
   <div class="revolution-slider">
     <ul>
        <!-- SLIDE  -->
        @foreach($content->slider as $sliders)
           <li data-transition="{{ $sliders->transition }}" data-slotamount="{{ $sliders->slotamount }}" data-masterspeed="{{ $sliders->masterspeed }}">
              <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
              <img src="{{ URL::asset($sliders->url) }}" alt="">
           </li>
        @endforeach
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I'm getting an error of

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\wamp\www\NitsEditor\resources\views\themes\Miracle\Plugins\Slider\2.blade.php) (View: C:\wamp\www\NitsEditor\resources\views\themes\Miracle\Plugins\Slider\2.blade.php)

While executing `diedump` the below code in `foreach loop`:

```
foreach ($getplugin as $item){

        $plugincontents[] = Plugin::findOrFail($item)->userplugins()->whereUserId($userid)->first()->pivot->contents;

}
dd($plugincontents);
```

I'm able to get the `JSON output` which holds the information of that particular view. Like this below:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "{"slider": [{"url": "img/home/bg.jpg", "slotamount": "7", "transition": "zoomin", "masterspeed": "1500"}, {"url": "img/home/bg2.jpg", "slotamount": "7", "transition": "zoomout", "masterspeed": "1500"}, {"url": "img/home/LOMEg.png", "slotamount": "7", "transition": "slidedown", "masterspeed": "1500"}]}"
  1 => "{"logo": {"logolink": "index.html", "logoimage": "img/home/nitseditorlogo.png"}, "pages": [{"pagelink": "index.html", "pagename": "Mysite"}, {"pagelink": "templates.html", "pagename": "Templates"}, {"pagelink": "aboutus.html", "pagename": "About Us"}, {"pagelink": "contactus.html", "pagename": "Contact Us"}]}"
]
```

Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, while doing cross checks I came to know that I need to `json_decode` in my data in views. I tried and got the result,

In my **Views** I did `json_decode` to the array like this:

```
@foreach($getplugin as $renderer)

    @include('themes.' . $template->theme->name . '.Plugins.' . $plugins->find($renderer)->type . '.' . $plugins->find($renderer)->id, ['contents' => json_decode($plugins->find($renderer)->userplugins()->whereUserId($userid)->first()->pivot->contents)])

@endforeach
```

And finally getting the results as desired.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `$getplugin = json_decode($template->templatedata);` use `$getplugin = json_decode($template->templatedata,true);`

Comment: If you add the `true` to `json_decode`, you would probably need to access your variables like `$sliders['transition']` inside of your foreach loop, since it's no longer a PHP object.

Comment: @DavidAngel : thanks for the guidance. You guys helped me to get the answer.